# How can I instantiate Web.Webpages.Html.HtmlHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

In asp.net mvc 3, the default html helper is from `System.Web.Mvc.Html`. I would like to use the helper from `System.Web.WebPages.Html`. Try as I might, I cannot seem to get an instance or access to `System.Web.WebPages.Html`. Here is what I have tried:

I tried all of this in razor inlined because I didn't think it was going to be that complex (hah).

This was with version

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

**Using new**

First I tried to simply instantiate it:

```
@{ var h = new System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper(); }
```

Which seemed to work until I ran it and got this:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0143: 
The type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' has no constructors defined
```

**Using Reflection**

So I figured it was an abstract class and tried to inherit it. Nope, it is an actual class, just with a private constructor. So I tried to reflect it

```
@using System.Reflection
@{
 BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = null;
 var instance = (System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper)Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper), 
    flags,
    null, 
    new object[] { ViewData.ModelState },
    ci
    );
}
```

Which lead to this error:

```
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: 
Constructor on type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' not found.
```

**Hoping for direct access**

Then I tried to just look for an active version:

```
var h = System.Web.WebPages.HelperPage.Html;
```

which lead to this error (h was null)

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I tried other versions of these which were also unsuccessful and feel at a loss of how to get an instance of this class around. I have access to `@Html` but, as I said, it is not the right `HtmlHelper` for this situation.

How can I get an instance of `System.Web.WebPages.Html`??

Comment: What for? Perhaps there's some other way to get what you're after? Is it a specific function?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - It is many functions. If you look at the documentation for both classes, there is no validation present in `Web.Mvc`, moreover, there are overloads which are not present in many functions. A very simple example of this is with the `Html.Label` helper, where `Mvc` only has 2 overloads, and Webpages has 3. This is deeper than that though, because I believe this discrepancy causes validation to fail to properly setup in various situations.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand you, but the MVC Helper has the same .. if not more (thanks to `LabelExtensions`) overloads. Also, there **are** validation routines in the MVC Helper.. Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve? I just don't see the reasoning..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - No offense, but your comment here is a repeat of what you said, and so I would direct you to my response. However, you are incorrect about the mvc helper, the class has less, as I pointed out (read the documentation). What more do you need to know? I am trying to instantiate an alternative `Html` helper.

Comment: I apologise. I was just trying to understand your problem more so that I could offer ways Mvc's built in functionality could help. I will point out that I have, in fact, read the documentation.

Comment: This question is not about how to use `Mvc`'s html helper. If you read the documentation then you would know there is no way to use `Html.Label("lbl","txt", new { @class = "attribute" });` with the `Mvc` helper (which is simple). A more complex example would be using the `DropDownFor` helper for a nested class with a `required` data attribute (which fails). Why get into all the side details? I feel like you are trolling and will respond with *why* to everything. It is the *how* that is important. **How can I instantiate WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper**?

Answer (score -4):

System.Web.WebPages.Html is a namespace not a class and you cannot instantiate a namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html(v=vs.111).aspx

I think you want System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper

Comment: Yes, you will notice that most of the examples point to instantiating `HtmlHelper`. I believe you misread the comment at the bottom of the post, and did not really look into the actual question.